# Hibernate OneToMany association on other than primary

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am trying to build one to many relationship between two tables using columns other than primary. I want a join between Asset.assetnum and SoftLink.assetnum. I am using hibernate 4 and it always generate relationship between primary.

from ASSET this_ left outer join SOFTLINKS soft3_ on **this_.ASSETID**=soft3_.ASSETNUM

What I actually want

from ASSET this_ left outer join SOFTLINKS soft3_ on **this_.ASSETNUM**=soft3_.ASSETNUM

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ASSET")
public class Asset {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ASSETID", nullable = false)
    private int assetid;

    @Column(name="ASSETNUM", nullable = true)
    private String assetnum;    

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "asset") 
    private List<SoftLinks> softlinks = new ArrayList<SoftLinks>(); 
}

@Entity
@Table(name="SOFTLINK")
public class SoftLinks {
    @Id 
    @Column(name="SOFTLINKID", nullable = false)    
    private String softlinkid;

    @Column(name="ASSETNUM", nullable = true)
    private String assetnum;    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ASSETNUM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Asset asset;
}
```

Comment: Look at the javadoc of JoinColumn: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29

Comment: Thanks. It worked very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `SoftLinks` class you need to change the `@ManyToOne` association to:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ASSETNUM", referencedColumnName = "ASSETNUM", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Asset asset;
```